# How do I find a "Save As" window with AutoHotkey?

Tags: autohotkey

I'm trying to find out if there is a "Save As" box open with this `WinExist` script

```
if WinExist,Save As,Save As
MsgBox, is there
else
MsgBox, is not there
```

Comment: 1. Did you use the AutoHotKey window Spy (right click on AutoHotKey icon) to see what the actual text is? 2. did you set the "SetTitleMatchMode, 2" as this will search anywhere through the windows title?

Answer (score 4):

Your original code is almost correct:

- The space between `if` and `WinExist` must be removed.
- The second parameter of `ifWinExist` is `WinTitle`. If the Save As dialog does not contain the text "Save As", you must remove that second parameter. This is the case on my Windows 7 system with English (Australia) regional settings.

Working examples:

```
; ifWinExist command
ifWinExist, Save As
    MsgBox, is there
else
    MsgBox, is not there

; if(expression) and WinExist() function
if WinExist("Save As")
    MsgBox, is there
else
    MsgBox, is not there
```

You can also combine criteria:

```
ifWinExist, Save As ahk_class #32770
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming it is an OSs' window, I would do something like,

```
^F1::       ;press Control + F1 to serch the window.
    if FindWindow()
        msgbox Found
    else
        msgbox Not Found
Return

FindWindow(strPartOfTitle="Save", strClass="#32770") {

    if (hWnd := WinExist("ahk_class " . strClass)) 
    {
        WinGetTitle, strWinTitle, ahk_id %hWnd%
        if InStr(strWinTitle, strPartOfTitle) 
            return true
        else
            return false
    } 
}
```